# App behavior with spaces and minimized window

Tags: dock, spaces, switching, window-manager

I would like to change the behavior when I click on an app that's not open on the current space. Right now, it goes to whichever space has that app. Instead, I'd like it to favor the current space, including minimized windows.

example: I have two open Chrome windows. One is minimized on space 1, and the second is open on space 2. The currently active space is 1.

What happens by default: I click the Chrome icon in the dock, and I am switched to space 2 to the open Chrome window there.

What I want to happen: The minimized window on space 1 is restored and made active.

What doesn't work: disabling switching spaces to an app to make it active. If I don't have a minimized window on the current space, then I do want it to switch spaces.
I tried this, it still doesn't restore the minimized windows. It just makes the app active on the current space. Then when I click the app again, it switches spaces, instead of restoring the minimized window. It only seems to restore the window when all the windows are minimized. How frustrating.

Basically I just want to swap the priorities of the two actions: unminimize and switch spaces.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this is possible, however you could use ctrl+click on the dock icon or long click anbd use the sub menu system to show windows / switch to windows.

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature should be [requested from Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) as it currently isn't possible.

It does makes much more sense, as the minimized windows are 'nowhere', so they shouldn't be attached to any desktop.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think its possible from apple.

Answer (score -1):

**No, there is not an option to change this behaviour currently.**

However, under Mission Control in your System pref you can disable "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application".

This does two things:

1. As intended: It doesn't jump to (using your example) the active window in space 2, giving you a chance to click on the minimized window in the taskbar.
2. As a hidden feature: If you click the icon a second time it sends you to the active window on space 2 (just like it does when the setting is enabled).

Comment: Please don't downvote correct answers, when there isn't a solution available that will solve your problem. @Community

Comment: This does not work in Catalina and with applications like Apple Music...